# Почему событие применяется не ко всем элементам?

Tags: jquery

Есть блоки

```
       <div id="cat-mini-item">
            <div id="cat-mini-itemName">
                Компьютеры
            </div>
            <div id="cat-mini-itemOpen"></div>

            <div id="cat-mini-list">
                <a href="">
                    <div id="cat-mini-list-item">
                        Ноутбуки
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    <div id="cat-mini-list-item">
                        Системные блоки
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    <div id="cat-mini-list-item">
                        Моноблоки
                    </div>
                </a>

            </div>  
        </div>

        <a href="">
            <div id="cat-mini-item-one">
                <div id="cat-mini-itemName">
                    Мониторы
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>

        <div id="cat-mini-item">
            <div id="cat-mini-itemName">
                Манипуляторы и аксессуары
            </div>
            <div id="cat-mini-itemOpen"></div>

            <div id="cat-mini-list">
                <a href="">
                    <div id="cat-mini-list-item">
                        Клавиатуры
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    <div id="cat-mini-list-item">
                        Компьютерные мыши
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a href="">
                    <div id="cat-mini-list-item">
                        Коврики
                    </div>
                </a>

            </div>  
        </div>
```

Пытаюсь присвоить блокам #cat-mini-item событие:

```
$.each($('#cat-mini-item'), function(index, value) { 
    $(this).on("click", function(){
    $(this).children('#cat-mini-list').slideToggle(300);
        $(this).css({"height":"auto"});
        $(this).css({"padding-bottom":"0"});
    });
});
```

Но данное событие присваивается, почему-то только первому (Компьютеры)

Comment: Все дело в том, что вы пытаетесь присвоить значение по `id`, который должен быть уникальным, для того, чтобы все работало, нужно использовать `class`

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Идентификатор на странице может быть только в единственном экземпляре, используйте классы:

```js
$.each($('.cat-mini-item'), function(index, value) {
  $(this).on("click", function() {
    $(this).children('.cat-mini-list').slideToggle(300);
    $(this).css({
      "height": "auto"
    });
    $(this).css({
      "padding-bottom": "0"
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cat-mini-item">
  <div class="cat-mini-itemName">
    Компьютеры
  </div>
  <div class="cat-mini-itemOpen"></div>

  <div class="cat-mini-list">
    <a href="">
      <div class="cat-mini-list-item">
        Ноутбуки
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <div class="cat-mini-list-item">
        Системные блоки
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <div class="cat-mini-list-item">
        Моноблоки
      </div>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>

<a href="">
  <div class="cat-mini-item-one">
    <div class="cat-mini-itemName">
      Мониторы
    </div>
  </div>
</a>

<div class="cat-mini-item">
  <div class="cat-mini-itemName">
    Манипуляторы и аксессуары
  </div>
  <div class="cat-mini-itemOpen"></div>

  <div class="cat-mini-list">
    <a href="">
      <div id="cat-mini-list-item">
        Клавиатуры
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <div class="cat-mini-list-item">
        Компьютерные мыши
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <div class="cat-mini-list-item">
        Коврики
      </div>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Так как `id` - уникальный идентификатор, если `css` может обращаться к нескольким элементам с одинаковым `id`, то javascript - нет.

Answer (score 1):

Все дело в том, что вы пытаетесь присвоить значение по `id`, который должен быть уникальным, для того, чтобы все работало, нужно использовать `class`

```js
$.each($('.cat-mini-item'), function(index, value) {
  $(this).on("click", function() {
    $(this).children('.cat-mini-list').slideToggle(300);
    $(this).css({
      "height": "auto"
    });
    $(this).css({
      "padding-bottom": "0"
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cat-mini-item">
  <div id="cat-mini-itemName">
    Компьютеры
  </div>
  <div class="cat-mini-itemOpen"></div>

  <div class="cat-mini-list">
    <a href="">
      <div class="cat-mini-list-item">
        Ноутбуки
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <div class="cat-mini-list-item">
        Системные блоки
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <div class="cat-mini-list-item">
        Моноблоки
      </div>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>

<a href="">
  <div class="cat-mini-item-one">
    <div class="cat-mini-itemName">
      Мониторы
    </div>
  </div>
</a>

<div class="cat-mini-item">
  <div class="cat-mini-itemName">
    Манипуляторы и аксессуары
  </div>
  <div class="cat-mini-itemOpen"></div>

  <div class="cat-mini-list">
    <a href="">
      <div class="cat-mini-list-item">
        Клавиатуры
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <div class="cat-mini-list-item">
        Компьютерные мыши
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="">
      <div class="cat-mini-list-item">
        Коврики
      </div>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```